# can't reach the cookies in the API with req.cookies.token return undefined

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, authentication, cookies

After login, the token is set in the res.cookie but I can't access it in the API. When I use req.cookies.token, it returns undefined. In the Postman I see that the cookies are set normally, but in the browser, there are no cookies. but when I use passportjs  GoogleAuth, there is no issue with the cookie.
Here is the code I use:
the login function:

```
//@desc login user
//@route /api/v1/auth/login
//@access public
export const logIn = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password }: User = req.body
    const USER = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            email
        } as User
    })

    if (USER && await bcrypt.compare(password, USER.password)) {
        res.cookie('token', generateToken(USER.id), {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
            maxAge: 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        })
        res.status(200).json({ message: "user logged in successfully", token: generateToken(USER.id) })
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "email or password is incorrect" })
    }
})
```

the tokengenerateor function :

```
function generateToken(id: string) {
    const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.TOKEN_KEY, {
        expiresIn: "15d"
    })
```

the middleware i use :

```
//middlewares
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors({
    origin: process.env.FRONT_URL,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
    credentials: true,
}))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
```

response headers when login with success is showen in the image.
[image: response headers after login]

I try to set the token in the cookies but in the api i can't access to it. i also set the with credentials to true when i send a request

Comment: dont think you are supposed to set http://localhost:3000 as the domain when you set the cookie. Think you can skip setting the domain entirely.  the domain part should only be the domain, not the scheme or port.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const handleRefreshToken = async (req, res) => {
    const cookies = req.cookies;
    if (!cookies?.jwt) return res.sendStatus(401);

    const refreshToken = cookies.jwt; // here is your refresh token 

    jwt.verify(
        refreshToken,
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        (err, decoded) => {
            if (err || /* condition */) return res.sendStatus(403);          
            const accessToken = jwt.sign(
                { /* put your data here to sign */},
                process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
                { expiresIn: '2m' }
            )
            res.json({ accessToken });
        }
    );
}

module.exports = { handleRefreshToken }
```

Comment: const cookies = req.cookies;
    if (!cookies?.jwt) return res.sendStatus(401); it will stop here